# How to make Visual Studio 2010 Class View default to showing open source file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Class View is the panel you get to from the View menu which shows your solution's source files in a tree view grouped by project.

When you open it, it defaults to showing all your classes.  But I usually want to see the outline of the particular class I am editing.  So I have to bounce down through all tree control, getting carpal tunnel at every hop.  At this rate, and I'll be waving ragged, arthritic claws before I finish this project - all thanks to Class View.

Searching using the search box at the top of the panel is not fast or direct enough.

I want to go direct to the class I have open so I can browse its members, and filter them using the preferences for this panel if necessary.

Anybody know how to make it default to showing the open class?  Or, alternatively, some other way to do what I want, maybe an extension?

Couldn't find anything in help or Tools:Options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change key shortcut that let you to open current class in class view. Tools -> Options -> Keyboard, command View.SynchronizeClassView